# using clustered indexes from point cloud in rgb image

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library

I'm working with depth map acquired from two images (i took it from opencv StereoBM) and now i need to find clusters in them
I decided to  use pcl region growing segmentation http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/region_growing_segmentation.php. I converted cv::Mat to point cloud after reading this article http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html and now i have cluster indexes 
This to functions here https://gist.github.com/Daiver/5586252
Now i want, to use these indexes to display clusters on depth map from StereoBM (cv::Mat)

I'm trying this  but I'm not satisfied with the results

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud; //cloud from depth map and rgb image
  std::vector <pcl::PointIndices> clusters;// clusters inices, extracted before
  for(int j = 0; j < clusters.size(); j++)
  {
      cv::Mat to_show = cv::Mat::zeros(288, 384, cv::DataType<uchar>::type);//image has size that equal size of rgb image and depth map        
      for(int i = 0; i < clusters[j].indices.size(); i++)
      {
        to_show.data[clusters[j].indices[i]] = 200;// regions in this Mat must be equal with regions from depth map
      }
      cv::imshow("", to_show);
      cv::waitKey();
  }
```

Result
Some cluster
[image]
Another cluster
[image]

Visualized cloud 
[image]

How i can project clusters to cv::Mat?
PS sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language

UPD
I've tryed to "restore" depth map by using loops like loops in mat_to_cloud function

```
int counter = 0;
cv::Mat to_show = cv::Mat::zeros(288, 384, cv::DataType<uchar>::type);
for(int i = 0; i < cloud->height; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < cloud->width; j++)
  {
    to_show.at<uchar>(i, j) = cloud->at(counter).z;
    counter++;
  }
}
```

[image]

And another order of loops
    int counter = 0;
    cv::Mat to_show = cv::Mat::zeros(288, 384, cv::DataType::type);
    for(int j = 0; j < cloud->width; j++)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < cloud->height; i++)
      {
        to_show.at(i, j) = cloud->at(counter).z;
        counter++;
      }
    }

[image]

I don't know why these image is similar

Comment: What exactly about the result is wrong or do you dislike? Also, which picture in the screenshots shows what?

Comment: I want to see separate clusters in depth map. Like single head or single lamp or single camera

Comment: That is what you want but what IS your result and what is wrong with it?

Comment: A picture to the right from depth map on screenshots is the result

Comment: please note that the correct tag is `point-cloud-library`, PCL originally stands for printer command language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, but my solution is a little dirty and silly.
I Made my own simple reprojection function

```
void straight_reproject_cloud(cv::Mat& img_rgb, cv::Mat& img_disparity, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& point_cloud_ptr)
{
    uchar pr, pg, pb;
    for (int i = 0; i < img_rgb.rows; i++)
    {
        uchar* rgb_ptr = img_rgb.ptr<uchar>(i);
        uchar* disp_ptr = img_disparity.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < img_rgb.cols; j++)
        {
            uchar d = disp_ptr[j];
            if ( d == 0 ) continue; //Discard bad pixels
            pb = rgb_ptr[3*j];
            pg = rgb_ptr[3*j+1];
            pr = rgb_ptr[3*j+2];
            //Insert info into point cloud structure
            pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
            point.x = j;
            point.y = i;
            point.z = d;
            uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(pr) << 16 |
                  static_cast<uint32_t>(pg) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(pb));
            point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
            point_cloud_ptr->push_back (point);
        } 
    }
}
```

This function adds points to cloud directly from images, without changes
New cloud is not coincided with old reprojection but i can work with it

And now points coordinates in cloud is concided to coordinates in images
I can show all clusters from cloud in image:

```
for(int k = 0; k < clusters.size(); k++)
{
    cv::Mat res = cv::Mat::zeros(img_rgb.rows, img_rgb.cols, CV_8U);
    //for(int i =0 ; i < point_cloud_ptr->points.size(); i++)
    for(int j =0 ; j < clusters[k].indices.size(); j++)
    {
        int i = clusters[k].indices[j];
        int x = point_cloud_ptr->at(i).x;
        int y = point_cloud_ptr->at(i).y;
        res.at<uchar>(y, x) = (int)(point_cloud_ptr->at(i).z);
    }
    cv::imshow("rec2", res);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

[image]

New cloud

[image]

Comment: Maybe my reprojection helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with PCL before but it looks like this line might be wrong:

```
// regions in this Mat must be equal with regions from depth map
to_show.data[clusters[j].indices[i]] = 200;
```

to_show is an opencv matrix but you use the indices from the point cloud. You need to convert the indices to pixel coordinates first.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think you are right, but indices from cloud depends on pixels from Mat, because I added points to cloud in this cycle:
  for (int i = 0; i < img_rgb.rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < img_rgb.cols; j++)
    {
/*some work*/
      point_cloud_ptr->push_back (point);//push_back added points to the end of vector of points? I thought, that the order of cloud points is the same as "data" points.
    }
  }

Comment: Might be right, I assume that your datatype is not correct, or there are alignment issues, or the image data is ordered in column major mode. Try checking these.

Comment: Do you mean to_Show's datatype? "or the image data is ordered in column major mode" I thought about it, but i don't know how check it

Comment: You could try to use the same loop you used for getting the indices for writing them back to the matrix. Those curve lines look like your step size is too small but then they also zigzag. I don't know, too hard to debug by looking at pictures. ;)